# How do I get a param from a non controller class in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this function in a non controller class

```
  def self.request(req_num, time)
    token = XsrfToken.last['token']
    db_parser = FetchDbParser.new
    used_url = ENUM_URLS[req_num]
    p token
    conn = Faraday.new(
      url: "#{BASE}#{used_url}",
      headers: { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'XSRF-TOKEN' => token }
    )
    response = conn.post do |req|
      req.body = { stationCodes: params[:id], collectTime: time }.to_json
    end
    res = JSON.parse(response.body)
    return unless res['success']

    parser_caller(req_num, res, db_parser)
  end
```

I need to get a param here `req.body = { stationCodes: params[:id], collectTime: time }.to_json`, but it's `undefined`

I also tried creating a method in the ApplicationController class, that was supposed to be called from that non-controller class and return me this param, but I got another error

```
`params': undefined method `filtered_parameters' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: you need to pass the parameter to this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`params` are a controller concept and are only available in the context of a controller action.

When you need a value from the `params` in another object, then you need to explicitly pass the `params` or at least the value that you need to the object.

For example, when your controller looks like this

```
def method_name
  YourClass.request(req_num, time)
end
```

and you require the value of `params[:id]` in the `self.request` method, then you need to change to controller method like this

```
def method_name
  YourClass.request(req_num, time, params[:id])
end
```

and your `self.request` like this

```
def self.request(req_num, time, id_from_params)  #<= see here
  token = XsrfToken.last['token']
  db_parser = FetchDbParser.new
  used_url = ENUM_URLS[req_num]
  p token
  conn = Faraday.new(
    url: "#{BASE}#{used_url}",
    headers: { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'XSRF-TOKEN' => token }
  )
  response = conn.post do |req|
    req.body = { stationCodes: id_from_params, collectTime: time }.to_json  #<= and here
  end
  res = JSON.parse(response.body)
  return unless res['success']

  parser_caller(req_num, res, db_parser)
end
```